# PgAdmin Saved Passwords on Shared Servers Broken for Non-Admins

Tags: python, docker, oauth, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

On a clean installation of PgAdmin in server mode based on official docker image version 6.10 I have the following issue:

Add a shared server as admin.

Login as an unprivileged user, set server Username under Properties > Connection.

Try to connect inserting the password and saving it - works.

Disconnect Server (or logout) then (re)Connect Server, and encounter error:

**not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)**

log says:

```
2022-06-07 09:03:28,114: ERROR     pgadmin:        'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 1: invalid start byte
pgadmin-and-backup-prod_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
pgadmin-and-backup-prod_1  |   File "/pgadmin4/pgadmin/utils/driver/psycopg2/connection.py", line 242, in _decode_password
pgadmin-and-backup-prod_1  |     password = password.decode()
pgadmin-and-backup-prod_1  | UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 1: invalid start byte
pgadmin-and-backup-prod_1  | 2022-06-07 09:03:28,116: ERROR     pgadmin:        not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
pgadmin-and-backup-prod_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
pgadmin-and-backup-prod_1  |   File "/pgadmin4/pgadmin/browser/server_groups/servers/__init__.py", line 1418, in connect
pgadmin-and-backup-prod_1  |     status, errmsg = conn.connect(
pgadmin-and-backup-prod_1  |   File "/pgadmin4/pgadmin/utils/driver/psycopg2/connection.py", line 294, in connect
pgadmin-and-backup-prod_1  |     is_error, errmsg, password = self._decode_password(encpass, manager,
pgadmin-and-backup-prod_1  | ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

I have changed config_local.py file to configure oauth2 authentication with Azure AD.

NOTE that fetching saved passwords seem to work fine for the admin user (can disconnect, reconnect no problem).

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed on version 6.15:  https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/release_notes_6_15.html

Issue #5367 - Ensure that the correct value should be returned if an exception occurs while decoding the password.